# How can I add values of different variables to a list upon click of button?

Tags: qt

Right now I am trying to create a shopping list program in which the user will add items to shopping list by clicking on a button. Please take a look at the screenshot, it will help.

So What I am trying to do is adding each ingredient to the text browser when clicking on the Tool Button next to it.

I tried using ui->listView->setText(), but I couldn't figure out how to pass a variable with it. Also, when I click on the button the list will only show one item at a time. I need to show all the items at the same time.

[image: This my current program]

```
 void shoppingList::on_add1_clicked()
{
    ui->listView->setText(ui->label_2); // this doesn't work
}

void shoppingList::on_add2_clicked()
{
    ui->listView->setText("ing2"); // this works but no efficient because only 1 item will be in list
                                      // + I need to pass a variable 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
void shoppingList::on_add1_clicked()
{
  ui->listView->append(ui->item_1->text());  // where ui->item_1 is a QLineEdit
  ui->listView->ensureCursorVisible();  // will scroll to bottom of list if necessary
}
```

Reference: [QTextEdit::append()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append),  [QTextEdit::ensureCursorVisible()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#ensureCursorVisible)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem , I think you should use  `void QTextEdit::append ( const QString & text )` to append new ingredients to the listview.

And you should use  `ui->listView->setText(ui->label_2->text());` to get the text displayed on the label.

(Although I am not seeing any label_2 object in the screenshot you attached to the post. So to add the ingredients , you probably should use `ui->listView->append(ui->item_2->text());` )